# SpriteKit: Font not showing up in editor

Tags: xcode, fonts, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

This question is regarding "No Font" problem in SKLabelNode that appears in SpriteKit scene editor in Xcode:
[image: SKLabelNode: No Font]

I pulled the recent changes in the project where a new font was added. Checked everything:

1. Font included into the **Copy Bundle Resources** - **YES**
2. Font included into Info.plist **UIAppFonts** - **YES**

But when I hit font selection **Attributes Inspector** - there simply no such font in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that, in order to be shown in Xcode, the font should be added to the Mac you work on. Quick way to do that:

1. Right-click on the font file > Open with External Editor (This will open Font Book)
2. Hit **Install**
3. Reopen scene. No need to reload Xcode, just close the .sks file (focus on other file) and open it again.

As the result "No Font" will disappear, fonts will be displayed correctly and you will be able to select the font in the picker.